# Pass multiple conditions as a string in where clause in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I am writing the following code in Spark, with the DataFrame API.

```
val cond = "col("firstValue") >= 0.5 & col("secondValue") >= 0.5 & col("thirdValue") >= 0.5"
val Output1 = InputDF.where(cond)
```

I am passing all conditions as strings from external arguments but it throws a parse error as `cond` should be of type `Column`.

For example:

```
col("firstValue") >= 0.5 & col("secondValue") >= 0.5 & col("thirdValue") >= 0.5
```

As I want to pass multiple conditions dynamically, how can I convert a `String` to a `Column`?

#### Edit

Is there anything through which I can read list of condition externally as `Column`, because I have not found anything to convert a `String` to a `Column` using Scala code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you may want to do something like the following:

```
InputDF.where("firstValue >= 0.5 and secondValue >= 0.5 and thirdValue >= 0.5")
```

The error you are facing is a parse error at runtime, if the error was caused by a wrong type passed in it would not even have compiled.

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@where(conditionExpr:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) (here provided for Spark 2.3.0) the `where` method can either take a sequence of `Column`s (like in your latter snippet) or a string representing a SQL predicate (as in my example).

The SQL predicate will be interpreted by Spark. However I believe it's worth mentioning that you may be interested in composing your `Column`s instead of concatenating strings, as the former approach minimizes the error surface by getting rid of entire classes of possible errors (for example parse errors).

You can achieve the same with the following code:

```
InputDF.where(col("firstValue") >= 0.5 and col("secondValue") >= 0.5 and col("thirdValue") >= 0.5)
```

or more concisely:

```
import spark.implicits._ // necessary for the $"" notation
InputDF.where($"firstValue" >= 0.5 and $"secondValue" >= 0.5 and $"thirdValue" >= 0.5)
```

`Column`s are easily composable and more robustly so than raw strings. If you want a set of conditions to apply you can easily `and` them together in a function that can be verified even before you even run the program:

```
def allSatisfied(condition: Column, conditions: Column*): Column =
    conditions.foldLeft(condition)(_ and _)

InputDF.where(allSatisfied($"firstValue" >= 0.5, $"secondValue" >= 0.5, $"thirdValue" >= 0.5))
```

You can achieve the same with strings of course, but this would end up being less robust:

```
def allSatisfied(condition: String, conditions: String*): String =
    conditions.foldLeft(condition)(_ + " and " + _)

InputDF.where(allSatisfied("firstValue >= 0.5", "secondValue >= 0.5", "thirdValue >= 0.5"))
```

Comment: Here I am getting Condition as string because I am reading that condition as argument in Spark-submit command. So I can not pass Column Type Externally. I updated Last line in question. Please have a look.

Comment: I've added an example that does the same using strings. Again, there's no need to do any conversion, Spark already natively accepts SQL predicates.

Comment: One more thing using this you can perform only `and` operation not `or`.

Comment: And if external string is like below 
`((firstValue >= 0.5 && secondValue >= 0.5) || (thirdValue >= 0.5 && fourthValue >= 0.5))` Then we can not achieve it using above code.

Can you please help me out with this. I have google it but not found anything like this.

Comment: You can have a method to do `and` and another to do `or` and combine the two.

Comment: Great answer! The composition is especially elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve similar thing and for Scala the below code worked for me.

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, _}

```
val cond = (col("firstValue") >= 0.5 & 
            col("secondValue") >= 0.5 & 
            col("thirdValue") >= 0.5)

val Output1 = InputDF.where(cond)
```